# Is there a "Rails way" to track metrics over time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have an Employees model and want to track how many total employees I have on every Friday and store the results in a file, is there a gem or some feature that would allow easy implementation of this?

My current plan is to use the [clockwork gem](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/clockwork) (final deployment isn't on a Unix server so no Cron jobs, unfortunately) to schedule a task that simply counts the number of employees and writes that to a model.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what will be your production server?

Comment: @YosepKim Windows Server 2008 with SQL Server 2008.

Comment: May I ask why you are using Windows stack for running a Rails app? I strongly recommend running it in Linux environment. Ruby ran just fine, but there were some issues with some gems in Windows, and Rails apps were running significantly slower than when they were on Linux. It may have gotten better, but there is a bigger community of people who run Rails on Linux than Windows...

Comment: It's out of my control, unfortunately. I don't run the stack and this must be hosted in house. I'll try and talk the sysadmin to get him to let me set up an Ubuntu server.

Comment: I guess running RoR is getting better. Read this article, if you have a chance. http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/5/11/deploying-rails-on-windows-servers/ The biggest problem I encountered was when I tried to run unit tests. It was taking very long time to run through them, although there were only few test cases. I guess it had hard time spinning up the test database from the schema.rb. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, having a scheduled job through Cron/clockwork or Windows services would be the best way to achieve this. Your requirement states that the total has to be calculated at a certain time. This requirement has nothing to do with a web application development framework, Rails or not.

Comment: So you'd recommend using Windows task scheduler to just run a rake task at a certain time? Is that possible within Windows?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was recommending. Yes, it is possible in Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had startd to investigate this but I haven't reached the point where I need to have this.

Basically my idea was to have some "settings class" (for example using `mongoid-app-settings` or the ActiveRecord equivalent), and a setup like this

```
class Stats
    setting :my_stat

    def compute_my_stat
        ...
    end

    def self.compute_statistics
      [:my_stat, ...].each do |stat|
        self.send("compute_"#{stat}")
      end
    end
end
```

Then you can start a rack task that would execute `Stats.compute_statistics`, using the scheduler you want

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you can use cron jobs, I recommend [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem.

If not, I don't know your server OS but I think the OS has schedule program like crontab. So you write .rake code to generate the file has total employees. And then Input "cd /path/to/app/root/ && bundle exec rake NAMESPACE:TASK" to the schedule program by program syntax